# jQuery Drag & Drop returns "Object has no method 'appendChild'" error

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

i have what i thought would be a simple drag and drop I can't seem to get to work. I simply want to move a dragged image into its target:

```
$('img').each(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  self.attr('draggable', 'true');
  self.bind('dragstart', function (e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', self.attr('id'));
  })
})
$('.drop-target').each(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  self.bind('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
  self.bind('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
  self.bind('drop', function (e) {
    var elemId = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    console.log("elem id: "+elemId)
    self.appendChild($(elemId));
    if(e.preventDefault){
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  });
})
```

So - the element ID is being passed without issue. I'm just getting a Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild' message in the console. thoughts?

Need more info?? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with this code.

### `appendChild` method on `jQuery` object

`self` in `self.appendChild($(elemId));` is a `jQuery` object, but **`appendChild()` is a method of DOM element**, this is why the error occurs.

### ID selector

Also you create **incorrect selector** from your ID. ID selector should start with `#`.

### Corrected code

After these fixes your code should look like this:

```
self.append($('#' + elemId));
```

Did it work? This may not be the only issue with this code.

Comment: @juliep: I am happy with that :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `appendChild()`.

Comment: @juliep: See my answer, there is another problem with that code.

Comment: yep - you're right. thanks! I was so focussed on the error I was missing the obvious selector issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not have an `.appendChild()` that I know of. You are probably looking for [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)